# Checking matching values in a list of files

Tags: r, list, match

Lets say we have list of files in the directory and want to check either `ref` values are exist or not in other files. If the number is exist output is `0` if not `1`.

## write files into directory

```
writeFiles <- function(n, maxRows=10){
  lapply(1:n,function(x) write.table(sample(sample(maxRows)[1],replace=F),paste(x,'.txt',sep=""), quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE,row.names=FALSE))
}

writeFiles(10,10)
```

this creates 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt... 10.txt files in the working directory.

## lets read these files

```
filesToProcess <- dir(pattern = "*\\.txt")

listofFiles <- lapply(filesToProcess, function(x) read.table(x, header = F))
```

> listofFiles

```
 [[1]]
   V1
 1  2
 2  3
 3  4
 4  1

[[2]]
  V1
1  1

[[3]]
  V1
1  1

[[4]]
  V1
1  4
2  1
3  5
4  2
5  3

[[5]]
  V1
1  3
2  2
3  4
4  1

[[6]]
  V1
1  4
2  5
3  2
4  3
5  1

[[7]]
  V1
1  1
2  2
3  4
4  3

[[8]]
  V1
1  3
2  5
3  6
4  2
5  4
6  7
7  1

[[9]]
  V1
1  1

[[10]]
  V1
1  1
2  3
3  2
```

desired output

note:location of the number doesnt matter.

```
ref<-seq(1:10)
ref      1.txt     2.txt   ......   10.txt 
1           1         0               0
2           0         1               0
3           0         0               0  
4           1         0               1 
5           1         0               1
6           1         1               0
7           0         0               1
8           1         1               0
9           0         0               1
10          1         0               1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
cbind(ref, sapply(lst, function(x) +(ref %in% x$V1)))
```

Comment: how can we put col names on top?

Comment: @Alexander The `sapply` returns a `matrix`.  If you need a data.frame, then `res <- cbind(ref, do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x) +(ref %in% x$V1))))` and change the column names with `colnames(res) <-  c('ref', paste0('V', 1:10))`